# Get Information From Parent With Chathead in Window Manager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an application like quickactions, see the video http://techcrunch.com/2015/09/20/disrupt-sf-2015-hackathon-winners/ for the quick preview.
Currently i have created a chat head which can be dragged across the screen. Here's the code i used.

```
notification = new TextView(this);
notification.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#494949"));
notification.setText("1");
notification.setId(nameid);
notification.setTextSize(19);


final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_imageview = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params_imageview.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);


final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_name = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params_name.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, imageid);
params_name.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, imageid);



parentlayout.addView(chatHead, params_imageview);// adding user image to                                                        // vie
parentlayout.addView(notification, params_name);
```

Now i want to get information about the app on which chathead is dropped, so that i can display the shortcut with Android Overlay. For eg when i drop the chathead on facebook app icon, it should display quick shortcuts.

I have gone thru all the manual before coming on stackoverflow.